# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (JavaScript/HTML in PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

This script I have on my site is causing some unexpected error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`
it should rewrite function of enter to act as a tab within the inputs on site form instead of submitting that form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('input').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    <--! says error is here within the $ symbol -->
    $(this).next('input').focus();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: This means you haven't included jQuery before using it

Comment: You need to load jQuery before running this code.

Comment: Thx guys im sorry for reposting this .. i though its different problem from other similar ones

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thats probably because jQuery isn't defined. (I'm assuming you are using juery).

Try including jQuery first:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('input').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    <--! says error is here within the $ symbol -->
    $(this).next('input').focus();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
 });
</script>
```